# Django reverse FK query

Tags: django, django-models

I have two tables:

```
class Task
    - id
    - order_id (FK)

class OrderItem
    - id
```

How would I query all `OrderItems` that have at least one Task pointing to it?

Something like `OrderItem.objects.filter(task_set__isnull=False)` ? What would be the correct query here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `task_set` (which is reverse lookups for model objects), you can do `task` (lowercase model name) - which is used for reverse queryset filtering.

```
ordereditems = OrderItem.objects.filter(task__isnull=False)
```

Read more on [lookups that span relationships here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
OrderItem.objects.filter(task__id__isnull=False)
```